# How to create IIS Rewrite for dynamic data from page

Tags: c#, iis, dynamic, url-rewriting

How do I create an IIS Rewrite rule that drags information from the page's information or a database?

```
Eg /hoteldetail?StayFK=1 becomes /hotel/ACT/hyatt-canberra
```

The data isn't part of the original url and the pages are dynamic c#.

Comment: That means you should implement such dynamic redirection inside your web app in C#, not ask IIS to do what it is not designed for.

Comment: OK, so how could this be done?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As Lex says there is no way to achieve drags information from the page's information or a database.

If you want to ahiceve this , I suggest you could try to write a custom http module or custom filter(asp.net MVC application) to hanlde the request and generate a right url by querying the database.

About how to create a custom module and use it, you could refer to this [article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3090997/how-to-work-with-httpmodules-in-aspnet.html).